# Looking for a lightweight-ish distributed DB/cache

Tags: distributed-caching, distributed-database

I will store simple plain text, but I'm looking for these features from a (D)DB/cache:

- Replication across all nodes
- Adding nodes to a live cluster
- It's free
- Persistence to disk (not to another DB)
- Uses relatively little resources

Apache ZooKeeper fails the DB requirement, but I kinda want to misuse it for my intentions...

Apache Cassandra fails the last requirement.

Redis fails at first requirement (unless you're ready to get your hands dirty?).

Hazelcast and Voldemort fail at persistence, AFAIK.

These are my top picks and now I'm wondering if I'm on the right track, or is there another solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the CouchDB family? [MemBase](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/membase-server), [BigCouch](http://bigcouch.cloudant.com/) and [Apache CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/).

Comment: MemBase looks like the thing I need!

Comment: When you say *replication across all nodes*, couchdb seems to be the thing you're looking for. Best of luck!

Comment: Oh, I was under impression I could configure MemBase to work that way.

Comment: I meant couchdb in the sense of couchdb-related products, not restricted to apache couchdb. Sorry for the confusion, you're absolutely right.